# What is the difference between a Justice, a Sword and a Mercy?

Tags: imperial-radch, ancillary-justice

In the *Imperial Radch* series by Ann Leckie, what is the difference between a Justice, Sword, and Mercy? I have a feeling it has to do with size or rank, but I am not sure.

*Please no spoilers, I have just finished the first book.*

Comment: For future reference: best way to avoid spoilers is to avoid websites like this one. I learned this the hard way.

Comment: Short spoiler-free answer: Justices are large, slow troop carriers, Swords are medium-sized fast, heavily armed warships (and consider themselves better than Justices are Mercies), Mercies are smaller, more lightly armed utility / patrol ships. The [long answer is here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/93205/what-differentiates-the-radchaai-warship-classes), but even though it's not very spoilery you still might want to read the other two books first.

Comment: Also note this related question: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/122384/how-are-radchaai-ships-and-crews-structured

Answer (score 1):

[Io9 has an infographic](http://io9.gizmodo.com/get-to-know-the-incredible-starships-of-ann-leckies-anc-1733743808) that details the features of the various ship classes. Ann Leckie [linked there via her blog](http://www.annleckie.com/2015/09/30/ancillary-ships-infographic/), so I assume it's pretty much legit. Difference is size and troup complement (or number of ancilliaries), although Swords and Mercie appear to be somewhat similar.

Comment: The g in blog is feeling left out, it didn't get included in your link. ;)